# Airflow background tasks

Tags: airflow

I have started to work with Airflow recently and I have two questions. I am currently using it as background on Ubuntu as I have created the two following services:

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/airflow-webserver.service
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/airflow-scheduler.service
```

It work well but, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to use the GUI when not connected to the VM? (It is currently impossible for me)
2. The scheduler does not work as soon as I stop the VM local forwarding. Is there a way to have it enables 24/7, whatever if my computer is on or off?

Any kind of explanation would be appreciated.

Edit:
According to this post [How do you keep your airflow scheduler running in AWS EC2 while exiting ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168300/how-do-you-keep-your-airflow-scheduler-running-in-aws-ec2-while-exiting-ssh)
running as a service seems to be enough to have the scheduler set even when not doing ssh. But in my case it is not working. Could it be because of the user name in the .service file? What should be the user name in the file?

Comment: 1. I am unable to comprehend your usecase. can you provide more info, If you stop your VM which has airflow installed and running as service how can you expect that you can  access the scheduler or UI on stopped VM.
2. If you require to access webserver without port forwarding you can allow access to port 8080 to your IP address using firewall.
3. Mostly services should be run using a separate user group which does not have login access.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ShahbazAli Let me thank you for you comment. Based on your, I have a better understanding about how the VM and webserver. I would like to clarify 3. as activating the scheduler without downtime when I do not ssh is my priority. Not sure where is the problem but I am not the root user. The files `airflow-scheduler.service` and `airflow-webserver.service` owner is the root user. Still they are given read/ write/exec right to group users. So why the Ariflow scheduler is not launching the tasks properly when not doing ssh please?

Comment: @ShahbazAli I changed the user and group to root in the `systemd` files and now the scheduler is working even if I do not SSH!!! I was stuck on that for days so thank you. But the question remains, why it was not working with 777 access right?!

Comment: I may not be able to exactly answer your question why it doesnt work with 777 access right, because it depends on how you did your installation of airflow and also how you created your service files. But I would like to inform you that its not a good practice to run a  service with root privileges or even give a 777 access rights to a folder.

Comment: In order to run airflow as a service, process is simple you install airflow on your machine and create systemd `service` files for running airflow in background. Before creating service files you create a separate user and group account for your service, suppose you create a user account with name `airflow` and group `airflow` this process can be done manually or by automation. This is what is being done by many system services like database or network services etc.

Comment: creation of user account will create a separate home directory for airflow. you need to disable login for this user as no one will be using this account to login. All your airflow related directories will be inside home directory named `airflow` now if you use same user and group in service files, your services will have automatically access to the required folders in filesystem thus you need not to run service with  root privileges neither give 777 access to any folder on you machine. This is much better way

Comment: @ShahbazAli Understood, thank you for guiding toward best practices.